# Adding a QuickReport file to my delphi7 project, cause an error

Tags: dll, report, runtime-error, delphi-7, quickreports

I'm using **Delphi 7** with **QuickReport 3** on **Win XP SP3**, it works till 2-3 days ago, but now when I create a project and add a report to it, I got this error:

> Error creating form: Access violation at address 00D23E66 in module 'borlndmm.dll'. Write of address 6F726600.

The `borlndmm.dll` is exists in `C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Bin\` directory; also I copied it to `Windows\system32` directory and also I re installed my Delphi but i get this error yet.

And when i run my old project(that used quickreport) in run-time, i got this error:

```
Debugger Exception Notification
Project MyProject.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 00404EE7 in module 'MyProject.exe'. Read of address 80000007'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.
```

Does anyone know where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete my windows profile and create a new profile, and the problem solved!